# Dell Poweredge R410 replace PERC S100 with PERC 6i

Tags: raid, dell, perc6, dell-poweredge

I want to replace the PERC S100 RAID Controller with a PERC6i to be able to use 4 SAS harddrives instead of only SATA drives. What exactly do I need for this, what I've got so far:

1. PERC6i PCIe x8 card.
2. 4 x SAS 300GB 15000rpm drives

Some questions I have

1. Do I need a different backplane to accomodate the SAS disks? If so, what kind of backplane?
2. Do I need a special cable to hookup the PERC6i with the backplane? If so, what kind of cable?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered just asking Dell?

Comment: +1, Dell will be more than happy to tell/sell you exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the answer above is correct - your question reads that you wish to replace your existing SATA drives with SAS - I'm guessing these are internal so the PERC 6i would be correct rather than PERC6e.

As far as I know, Dell didn't make a SATA specific backplane so there should be no need to change backplane or cables.

You may also wish to look into the PERC H700 controller - this is the newer replacement to the 6i - both are compatible with the R410.

Answer (score 0):

Robe,

> PERC6i PCIe x8 card.

You need PERC 6/e not "i" as it means internal controller.

> 4 x SAS 300GB 15000rpm drives

It can be hot-plug HDDs:

- 2.5” SATA SSD, SAS (10K)
- 3.5” SAS (15K), nearline SAS (7.2K), SATA (7.2K)

For this option you will need a new backplane and new enclosures for disks (not cheap).

Or cabled:

> 3.5” SAS (15K, 10K), nearline SAS (7.2K)

Best if you don't need hotplug capabilities.

http://www.dell.com/downloads/emea/products/R410_spec_sheet.pdf

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you have any idea on the cable to use to connect the PERC controller to the backplane, is this a SAS to mini-SAS cables, I'm trying to find the specs for such a cable, but not succesful so far.

Comment: From the looks of it you will need an SFF8484 to SFF8087 forward breakout cable.

Answer (score 0):

Robe, I'm a little confused if you R410 is a cabled HDD unit or hotswap HDD unit.

You can go from hot swap to cabled but not cabled to hot swap.  You would need a new R410 to accommodate the backplane if your unit is cabled HDD.

That being said, the cable you would need to use SAS drives with PERC6i and cabled drives is Dell p/n M322G, Mini-SAS to cabled HDD.  There may be other part numbers that work but that is the only one I have encountered.

If by chance your machine is hot swap HDD and you just want to use SAS drives, then all you need is the PERC6i card and the cable (either Dell p/n Y180K or 69V70) will work.

Comment: PERC6i really just means it is controlling internal drives versus PERC6e controlling an external array.  The PERC6i card can come as either integrated or as an adapter.  If the poster plans to use the PERC to control the drives that are physically located in the R410 then he needs the PERC6i, if he hooking up the R410 to an array like the MD1000 or something then he needs the PERC6e.
http://www.dell.com/content/topics/topic.aspx/global/products/pvaul/topics/en/us/raid_controller?c=us&l=en&cs=555