# Dell PowerEdge R410 Non hot plug HDD change to Hot plug

Tags: dell-poweredge

I got one question:
Can I change Dell PowerEdge R410 from version non hot plug to version hot plug?

I bought non hot plug version, but I need hot plug? What can I do now?

Regards

Comment: Have you spoken to Dell Support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dell Poweredge R410 replace PERC S100 with PERC 6i](https://serverfault.com/questions/299926/dell-poweredge-r410-replace-perc-s100-with-perc-6i)

See there.  The server backplane you have won't accomodate the change...you'd need a new R410.

Comment: Is it different case?

Comment: ?  The server you have would need a new backplane and internal components.  Contact Dell but you won't like the answer.

Comment: Thanks, i did contact with dell and they say no, but last time when I asked them if it is possible to change power suply from not redundant to redundant they also say no, but we did it without sending to manufacturer this server.